# How to extract / isolate an integer from an API content bytes object?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm requesting a coin price from the CoinGecko api, but it outputs a bytes object and I can't work out how to simply extract the price as an integer. I've tried `data.content["nano"]["usd]`, which would seem the most obvious way but it results in this error:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'bytes object' has no attribute
>   'nano'

This is the process:

```
data = requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=nano&vs_currencies=usd")
```

Calling this in jinja2 `{{ nanoprice.content }}` gives me the bytes object:

```
b'{"nano":{"usd":1.18}}'
```

I've tried converting it to a string and extracting the float but it seems way too complicated and still results in a list rather than an integer.

```
import requests, ast, re

nanoprice = requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=nano&vs_currencies=usd").content
nanoprice = "".join( chr(i) for i in nanoprice)
nanoprice = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", nanoprice)
```

Comment: The bytes object is JSON and needs converting using the `json` module. That will give you a dictionary which can be indexed using the `'nano'` and '`usd'` keys.

Comment: Get the parsed Python dictionary from the response with `requests.get(...).json()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you might consider convert data to .json format, like this:
    `nanoprice.json()`
then you can use `nanoprice['nano']['usd']` to get what you need

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple json use case.

Try to read the `json` from response and further can be treated as `dict`:

```
data = requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=nano&vs_currencies=usd")

d=data.json()
print(d['nano']['usd'])
```

Hope this helps.